# "Any English I have learned" vs. "All the English I have learned"

Tags: word-choice, determiners

Is it correct to say: ***Any English*** I have learned has been from movies and the Internet or is it better: ***All the English*** I have learned has been from movies and the internet?

Comment: General Reference. *Any* here is self-deprecating, in that it implies not much may have been learned at all/

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *any* by itself implies negativity, correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you mean to say.

"*Any English I have learned...*" means that I have learned something and if any of what I've learned can be called English it came from movies and the internet.

"*All the English I have learned...*" means that I have, in fact, learned some English and it came from movies and the internet.